# How does poweroff work in Linux?

Tags: linux, reboot, poweroff

When using

```
poweroff -f
```

in the terminal it turns off the computer. A similar thing happens when using

```
reboot -f
```

it turns off and then back on again in a restart.

How can it be, that the computer "knows" to turn back ON again, when it has been powered off? Doesn't all the electricity "stop" from powering the CPU, RAM etc., so how can it remember to start the computer again, and which resources does Linux use for this?

Comment: Shutdown shouldn’t be restarting the machine, but a reboot, is a reboot it’s a specific power-state supported by the processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot is a function of the BIOS.

When the operating system has terminated all its graceful shutdown operations,
such as terminating all processes and system services,
and when it is ready for shutdown or reboot, then it calls the BIOS.

For a reboot, rather than shutdown, it will call a different BIOS function.
Reboot is called "warm boot", since power (and the RAM) is not turned off.
It is different from a real shutdown where power is turned off, which is why
it is called *warm* startup. Since power is not turned off, the computer
does not cool down.

Comment: It would theoretically possible for the OS to implement "reboot" as "1. program the BIOS RTC to wake up at current time plus ten seconds, 2. tell the BIOS to turn off the computer." In one of the devices my employer makes, they have actually implemented a "powercycle" command which asks the power distribution unit to disconnect the power rails to the device for 5 seconds. This means a device can basically pull its own power plug and plug itself in again!